# express.js: changing order of router and static makes 404 error on static files

Tags: static, express, router

At the time I use

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', consolidate.underscore);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);
require('./routes/index_roote')(app);
```

Here are my routes in `./routes/index_roote`:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  });
  app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('Ok');
  });
};
```

My views are simple html files as underscore templates.
If I set **app.router** before **static** (as in autogenerated app)

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
require('./routes/index_roote')(app);
```

I receive **404** when try to get static resources such as scripts, styles and images. Why?

Here index_roote module code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('index');
    });

    app.post('/', function(req, res){
      res.end('Ok');
    });
};
```

**index.html** is in vews folder

Other static files are in
-public
--images
--scripts
--styles

Comment: I can run both variants of this code on my machine without receiving 404s. You could try recreating the project in a new route directory to rule out local file system settings (maybe permissions are the culprit?).

Answer (score 1):

`app.use()` accepts express middleware as input and adds it to a middleware stack. Each piece of middleware has a function `next()` which executes the next piece of middleware in the stack as a callback. Thus, the order in which you add middleware with `app.use()` matters, as that will be the order of your middleware stack.

`app.router` is the middleware responsible for handling routes, like those you define with `app.get()`. In fact, `app.get()` uses `app.router` even if you do not explicitly add it to the middleware stack; it will add it at the point when the route is defined. When routes and static file serving are both being used, it is considered safer to explicitly use the router middleware first in order to avoid cases where a route is hidden by a poorly named static file. Express does this for you when it autogenerates the app file.

Based on the code you've shown here, it appears that you have a file called `index.html` in your `public` folder, which you're attempting to render using underscore. There are a couple of problems here. The name 'index.html' receives special handling when placed in your static folder. If your static file middleware comes first, Express will handle requests for root by serving `index.html`. This is why your code works when your static file middleware comes before `app.router`. **Note that index.html is not being rendered.**

When `app.router` comes first, requests for root are handled by `app.get()`, and you are attempting to render `index.html`. However, `app.render()` expects the file to be located in a file called `views`. You can change this behavior by doing this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
```

instead of what you are doing now:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

**In summary:**

As your code is currently written, you get 404s when `app.router` comes first because it causes your route for '/' to be used. You handle this route by rendering a file which is in the wrong folder (`public` instead of `views`). When `app.router` comes second, you are serving `index.html` (without rendering it) because Express will serve files with this name when you receive requests for '/'.

Comment: There are no one router which might match any static resource - all routers have definite rotes not with pattern match!
How can I find where i might be a problem?

Comment: @user2627000 feel free to provide more information, such as all of your routes. I'm about to add an example to demonstrate what I'm talking about above.

Comment: here is index_route

    module.exports = function(app) {
     app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('index');
     });
     
     app.post('/', function(req, res){
      res.end('Ok');
     });
    };

Comment: Could you please update your question with index_route included? Also, what sort of file are you rendering? Can you include the lines where you set your view engine and the location of your views? I believe I've solved your problem, but you need to update your question with this information so that the answer makes sense.

Comment: there is no file index.html in public. It sits in vews folder and it renders perfectly but styles and scripts are not found 404 in second variant of middlewares call!

Comment: What exactly are the static resources you're failing to load then? You must always be loading index.html then, right? Please provide more specific information.

Comment: No, I never call `http://mySite/index.html`!
index.html is used as template and is in views folder and is rendered only in appropriate route.
Scripts and styles are not found

Comment: And your scripts and styles are in the public folder, I assume?

Comment: this answer didnt help me.
any new suggestions?

Comment: @user2627000 did you rule out directory permissions? As I said above, I can run both versions of your code as described without 404s. This implies that the problem is with your environment, or else you haven't included all relevant code.